# Doubts regarding reading total number of words from the file

Tags: python

I am trying to read files from a directory and write the first sentence from each file into a new file until 100 words(or little more than 100, since I want to write complete sentences) are written into the new file.

I am doing in the following way:

```
f = open(file1.txt, "w")
f.close()
for d_file in os.listdir(path):
    d_file_path = os.path.join(path, d_file)
    if os.path.isfile(d_file_path):
        with open(d_file_path, "r") as f:
            first = f.readline()
            f1 = open ("file1.txt", "r")
            textInput = f1.read()
            f1.close()
            l = len(textInput.split(' '))
            print l
            if l >= 0 and l <= 100:
                f2 = open("file1.txt", "a")
                f2.write(first)
                print first
```

But, I'm getting wrong output in its print statement, even though it writes correctly into the new file.

My questions are:
Why am I getting the value of "`l`" as 0 two times? 
Also, when I simply find the total number of words in the file after it has been written into:

```
>>>f = open(file1.txt, 'r')
>>> text = f.read()
>>> l = len(text.split(' '))
>>> print l
```

I get: 111

However, the file is:

```
An influential lawmaker from the governing Labor Party on Saturday backed Spanish requests to question former Chilean dictator Gen. Augusto Pinochet, in London for back surgery, on allegations of genocide and terrorism.
British police said Saturday they have arrested former Chilean dictator Gen. Augusto Pinochet on allegations of murdering Spanish citizens during his years in power.
Eight years after his turbulent regime ended, former Chilean strongman Gen. Augusto Pinochet is being called to account by Spanish authorities for the deaths, detention and torture of political opponents.
Former Chilean dictator Gen. Augusto Pinochet has been arrested by British police on a Spanish extradition warrant, despite protests from Chile that he is entitled to diplomatic immunity.
```

Aren't there 114 words?

Can someone please answer my questions?

EDIT:

Now I'm doing: `l = len(textInput.strip().split())` and it gives me 114 words as the count, but that print statement is still the same. Now the output is like:

```
0
An influential lawmaker from the governing Labor Party on Saturday backed Spanish requests to question former Chilean dictator Gen. Augusto Pinochet, in London for back surgery, on allegations of genocide and terrorism.

0
British police said Saturday they have arrested former Chilean dictator Gen. Augusto Pinochet on allegations of murdering Spanish citizens during his years in power.

32
Eight years after his turbulent regime ended, former Chilean strongman Gen. Augusto Pinochet is being called to account by Spanish authorities for the deaths, detention and torture of political opponents.

56
Former Chilean dictator Gen. Augusto Pinochet has been arrested by British police on a Spanish extradition warrant, despite protests from Chile that he is entitled to diplomatic immunity.

86
President Fidel Castro said Sunday he disagreed with the arrest in London of former Chilean dictator Augusto Pinochet, calling it a case of international meddling.

114
114
114
114
114
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If your file1.txt has the contents that you posted your first print statement should print 114. Why dose it print 0? And also you are not closing the file after your write.

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry, I edited my code in the question. Have a look there to understand better. file1.txt was a file that was created before running this for loop.

Comment: Oh! That was because of not closing the file. Sorry about that. Thanks so much! :D

Comment: Since you are using the same file to write multiple times, you need to close it to read and get the correct length. So do 'f2.close()' just before you do 'print first'

Answer (score 0):

There are 114 words as you said. How ever you are splitting on ' '. Newline is not counted as ' '. So the last word in first line 'terrorism.' and the first word in the next line, 'British', are counted as one word in the format 'terrorism.\nBritish'. Same thing for two more lines. So a total of three words are joined with the last word in the previous sentence giving you three less words.

If you want to split on spaces and new lines as well, just use split() with no arguments and it should have 114 words. Details below from the doc [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html):

```
str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])
```

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is
>   applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single
>   separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start
>   or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently,
>   splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace
>   with a None separator returns [].

And for your another question of what is being printed, please upate your code with exactly what you have. As I see it, you are missing a quote around file1.txt and you may be missing other stuff too.